# Input Mask in ASP MVC Core using DisplayMetadata Provider

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was trying to find a way to implement Input Mask by passing custom attribute from Model Class in MVC ASP NET Core and built HTML attribute accordingly into HTML element .below is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share with you on how you apply the Input Mask using DisplayMetadata Provider as it is different than other version.
Here are brief steps more info on this can be find it in this link: [In MVC Core Passing custom attribute from Model class to HTML element "e.g.:Input Masking"](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1243346/In-MVC-Core-Passing-custom-attribute-from-Model-cl)  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1243346/In-MVC-Core-Passing-custom-attribute-from-Model-cl

1- Create Custom Attribute e.g.:HTMLMaskAttribute , inherit from Attribute Class

2- Create custom DisplayMetadataProvider by implementing the interface IDisplayMetadataProvider , this provider will read the new attribute from the model class .

3-register CustomMetadataProvider in the startup class of MVC application

4-In Model Class  add the new custom attribute "mask" in the property you need to create a mask of it example Phone number.

5- I am using Masked Input Plugin for my example download it  and  include the jQuery and masked input javascript files to your specific view page or to your _Layout.cshtml page .

6- add this script into your view either _layout.cshtml or specific view :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
   $('[mask]').each(function (e) {
       $(this).mask($(this).attr('mask'));
   });
   });
   </script>
```

7- create the view and include the Property that has an attribute

8- Run the application and notice the html attribute mask has been added for to the property Phone1

```
<input name="Phone1" class="form-control valid" id="Phone1" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value="(123) 456-7890" mask="(999) 999-9999">
```

Comment: I follow the steps but in my view my custom attribute isn't in the field. There is some extra configuration to render the attribute?